# linear programming issue

Tags: linear-programming

Hi I need help regarding a linear programming math problem. What I need is to formulate the equations. I tried this. But no idea whether the equations are correct.

[image]

[image]

What I need to know is whether my following decisions are correct.

Let's assume the number of tons sold from Spring is X1, Autumn = X2 and Winter=X3

Then based on the demand,

```
X1<= 4500
X2<=4000
X3<=4000
```

Profit = Selling price- Product cost- Purchase cost

```
Revenue = 60X1+55X2+60X3
Production Cost = 5X1+ 4X2+5X3
```

My issue is regarding the material cost(Purchase cost)

the minimum cotton cost was taken as,

```
(0.5 X1 + 0.6 X2 + 0.4 X3)30 --> Lets assume this as A
```

the minimum wool cost was taken as,

```
(0.3 X1 + 0.4 X2 + 0.5 X3)45 --> Lets assume this as B
```

the minimum silk cost was taken as,

```
(0.2 X1 + 0.1 X3 )50 --> Let's assume this as C
```

So the objective function is to maximize the profit,

```
60 X1 + 55 X2 + 60 X3 - (5 X1 + 4 X2 + 5 X3) -A -B -C
```

Are there more constraint functions. Am I missing anything? Really appreciate the help. At least someone who can mention the mistake I have done is highly appreciate.